# Need to shorten the SQL Query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(spent_time) AS spent_time_01,
    COUNT(vpno) AS spend_time_cnt_01
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         LEAD(create_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CAST(vpno AS INT)) AS lead,
         DATEDIFF('second', create_ts::timestamp, LEAD::timestamp) AS spent_time,
         *
     FROM 
         table_1) A
WHERE 
    item_category = 'A'
    AND pid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    id
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(spent_time) AS spent_time_02,
    COUNT(vpno) AS spend_time_cnt_02
FROM
    (SELECT 
         LEAD(create_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CAST(vpno AS INT)) AS lead,
         DATEDIFF('second', create_ts::timestamp, LEAD::timestamp) AS spent_time,
         *
     FROM 
         table_1) A
WHERE 
    item_category = 'B'
    AND pid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    id
```

I tried the below but I'm not getting the correct results. I think I'm missing something in the query.

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN pid IS NOT NULL 
             AND vpno IS NOT NULL 
             AND item_category = 'A' THEN spent_time END) AS spent_time_01
   ,COUNT_IF(vpno IS NOT NULL 
             AND item_category = 'A' 
             AND pid IS NOT NULL) AS spend_time_cnt
```

Someone kindly guide me on this.

Comment: You don't have `vpno is not null`  in the where clause of query 1 and query 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if we are trying for Code Golf (smaller code) Lukasz answer can be rewritten a couple line less, and smaller by moving the `lead` value into the only place it is used, and not have a CTE as it's only used once, and just have it as a subselect. Moving the WHERE filters into the select, and swapping from CASE to IFF. But these are points I have made before..

Also by only asking for the columns you want in the sub-select, the compile can be faster on cold meta data. but those are details that don't matter here.

```
SELECT id,
    SUM(iff(item_category = 'A', spent_time, null)) AS spent_time_01,
    COUNT(iff(item_category = 'A', vpno, null)) AS spend_time_cnt_01,
    SUM(iff(item_category = 'B', spent_time, null)) AS spent_time_02,
    COUNT(iff(item_category = 'B', vpno, null)) AS spend_time_cnt_02
FROM (
  SELECT id, item_category,
     DATEDIFF('second', create_ts::timestamp, (LEAD(create_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY vpno::INT))::timestamp) AS spent_time
  FROM table_1
  WHERE pid IS NOT NULL
    AND item_category IN ('A', 'B')
)
GROUP BY id;
```

But I do tend to prefer CTE for readability and I don't like over long lines, so even I will give my points vote to Lukasz's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Common part to be turn into CTE and item_category moved as conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
     LEAD(create_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY vpno::INT) AS lead,
     DATEDIFF('second', create_ts::timestamp, LEAD::timestamp) AS spent_time
  FROM table_1
)
SELECT id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_category = 'A' THEN spent_time END) AS spent_time_01,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_category = 'A' THEN vpno END) AS spend_time_cnt_01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_category = 'B' THEN spent_time END) AS spent_time_02,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN item_category = 'B' THEN vpno END) AS spend_time_cnt_02
FROM cte
WHERE pid IS NOT NULL
  AND item_category IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id;
```